# getting "Cannot read property "map" of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am getting "Cannot read property "map" of undefined (it is referring to tradeData) from the TradeDataList.js file. I am calling an API that is called through search term that is passed to "unirest" get function. I have setup context API passing some centralized values to various other files. I have it set up as an array in the useState. I am loosing my head with this if anyone can help please. The files I have are the following:

context.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useCallback } from 'react'
var unirest = require('unirest');

const url = 'https://api.someurl.com/oauth/client_credential/accesstoken' ;
const Browse_URL = 'https://api.someurl.com/tradesregister/v1/browse' ;

const MY_API_KEY = 'EpVhCPGX4lzMwzdXVKG7yYFubGtwmlYU4343434';

const Authorization = 'Basic RXBWaENQR1g0bHpNd3pkWFZLRzd5WUZ1Ykd0d21sWVU6M2NvcEVuQTVEZlJXZ3BSYw==' ;

const AppContext = React.createContext()

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [token, setToken] = useState('') ;
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true) ;
    const [tradeData, setTradeData] = useState([]) ;
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')
 
    const getToken = () => {
      unirest.get(url)
        .header({'Accept': 'application/json', 'authorization': Authorization})
        .query({"grant_type": "client_credentials"})
        .end(function (response) {
          const token = response.body["access_token"] ;
          //console.log(token) ;
          setToken(token)   
        })
  }


useEffect (() => {
  // call the getToken function
  getToken() ;
  
}, [])

//Get the new token to access trade data
const newAuth = 'Bearer ' + token 

    return (
        <AppContext.Provider
          value={{ token,
                   MY_API_KEY,
                   newAuth,
                   Browse_URL,
                   loading,
                   setTradeData,
                   tradeData,
                   setLoading,
                   searchTerm,
                   setSearchTerm 
                  }}
               
        >
          {children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
      )
  }


export const useGlobalContext = () => {
    return useContext(AppContext)
  }
  
  export { AppContext, AppProvider }
```

SearchForm.js (call starts from here )

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useGlobalContext } from '../context'
import TradeDataList from './TradeDataList'
//import Loading from './Loading'
var unirest = require('unirest');

const SearchForm = () => {
  const {searchTerm, setSearchTerm,loading, setLoading, tradeData, setTradeData, MY_API_KEY, newAuth, Browse_URL } = useGlobalContext();
  //const [tradeData, setTradeData] = useState([]) ;

  const getTrade = () => {
    setLoading(true)
    unirest.get(Browse_URL)
     .header({'Accept': 'application/json', 'authorization': newAuth, "apikey": MY_API_KEY })
     .query({"searchText": searchTerm })
     .end(function (response) {
        const tradeData = response.body ;
        //console.log(tradeData) ;
        setTradeData(tradeData)
        setLoading(false);
      })
  }
  
  useEffect (() => {
    // call the getTrade function
    getTrade() ;
  }, [])

 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault() ;
   getTrade() ;
  }
 
  console.log('here is the data' ,tradeData)

  return (
    <section className="section-search">
      <form className="search-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-control">
          <label htmlFor='searchTerm'> search trade licence info</label>
           <input 
             type='text' 
             id='searchTerm' 
             //ref={searchValue} //reference
             value={searchTerm}
             //onChange={searchTrade}
             onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
             />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      
      <div className="cocktails-center">
           <TradeDataList tradeData={tradeData} />
      </div>
      
    </section>
     
  )
}


export default SearchForm
```

TradeList.js

```
import React from 'react'
import TradeData from './TradeData'
//import Loading from './Loading'
//import { useGlobalContext } from '../context'

/**
 * This page displays TradeData and loading
 */

const TradeDataList = ({ tradeData }) => {
   

  //display loading while cocktails are being loaded
  
  return (
    <section className="section">
      <h2 className="section-title">
       Trade Data
      </h2>
      {/* <h2>cocktail list</h2> */}
      <div className="cocktails-center">
        {tradeData.map((trade) => {
           // this is to be handled by Cocktail component
            return <TradeData key={trade.licenceID} {...trade} />
        })}

      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default TradeDataList
```

TradeData.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

//image,name,id,info,glass
const TradeData = ({
    licenceID, 
    licensee, 
    licenceName,
    licenceNumber,
    licenceType,
    status, 
    suburb, 
    postcode,   
    businessNames,  
    categories, 
    classes 
   }) => {

  return (
    <article className="cocktail">
      <div className="img-container">
         <h1>This is header </h1>
      </div>
      <div className="cocktail-footer">
        <h3>{licenceID}</h3>
        <p>{licensee}</p>
        <h4>{licenceName}</h4>
        <p>{licenceType}</p>
        {/* <Link to={`/cocktail/${id}`} className="btn btn-primary
           btn-details">details</Link> */}
      </div>
    </article>
  )
}

export default TradeData
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your TradeList.js you simply need to add a check condition:

```
<div className="cocktails-center">
        {tradeData?tradeData.map((trade) => {
           // this is to be handled by Cocktail component
            return <TradeData key={trade.licenceID} {...trade} />
        }):null}

      </div>
```

Comment: I ma passing the data correctly, even though I put conditional statement still is not working for me??

Comment: what output it gives after you apply conditional statement?

Comment: try doing a console.log of your tradeData and check if your treeData is actually defined or not.even after the conditional rendering it's not working then that means treeData is an empty array(if no error is being thrown after using the conditional statement)

Comment: I ti sgiving me  this line:``` This message is from TradesDataList (11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] ``` and the next line the same message but it displays this ```TradeDataList.js:12 This message is from TradesDataList undefined ```

Comment: It is giving back the arrays but hen next line it showing the same but undefined !!

Comment: then that means there is some issue with tradeData which is being passed to TradesDataList

Comment: Also is your UI displaying tradeData or not?

Comment: Sakshi... guess what I got it working now... thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

***Another alternative solution***

```
 { tradeData && tradeData.map((trade) => {
           // this is to be handled by Cocktail component
            return <TradeData key={trade.licenceID} {...trade} />
        })}
```

*Note: The `.map` function is only available on array.
If data isn't in the format you are expecting it to be (it is `{}` but you are expecting `[]`).*

Comment: Do you mean my data is  { } instead of an array [ ] ?

Comment: had that been the case then the error would have been something like `map function does not exist on tradeData`.